# Why can't I parse this JSON file with Node.js?

Tags: json, node.js

Here is my simple `test.js` file.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

And here is my JSON data which is according to JSONLint a valid JSON.

```
{   
    "metaData": {      
        "num_Questions": "50",
        "non_uunique_questions_retrieved": "1",
        "custumSpecieList": []   
    },
   "questionData": [      
        {         
        "name": "FirstName",
             "id": "1221",
             "extraInfo": []      
        }
   ],
   "loadTime": "0.243357896805"
}
```

I got the following error when I run `test.js` file.

```
"undefined:1
{   
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token  
    at Object.parse (native)"
```

Comment: Try replacing `test.json` with `./test.json`

Comment: also try using require with the path to test.json relative to the running script

Comment: as @PedroOtero mentioned: `var obj = require('./test.json');`

Comment: Still the same error with ```./test.json```

Comment: there are no errors for me i ran it using node 2.2.6 and 4.4.5 what version and settings are you running also when i linted the json it saying valid json

Comment: I use node ```v4.4.5```

Comment: Verify that `file.json` stored as `utf8`.

Comment: Nothing to be found here, the JSON is perfectly fine. There must be a hidden character causing this.

Comment: I even removed ```utf8``` from the argument. Not working either.

Comment: @cviejo it seems like it is. I manually retyped the JSON file and now it's working. How can I remove those hidden character though? My JSON is fairly big.

Comment: I use Sublime Text

Comment: You can use a regex to against the file contents before parsing it or use a different parser that doesn't break with an illegal char.

Comment: You must save file.json as `utf8`. Also verify that you don't set BOM-mark. `fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8'` is equals to `fs.readFile('test.json', ...` because utf8 is default.

Comment: I have delete the text from json file and paste it again as plain text. Now it's working. As @cviejo said, hidden characters are giving me problem here.

Comment: It's not a hidden character. It be BOM ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark ), I think. Some editor saves `utf8` text with lead BOM-mark by default.